# Showing two sentences are provably equivalent (Fitch-style)

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 289, exercise G. 1), asks:

**G.** *Show that each pair of sentences is provably equivalent.*

1. $\forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x)); \neg\exists x(A(x) \wedge B(x))$

I need to provide two proofs in order to achieve that result.
Struggling with the second one, that is: $\neg\exists x(A(x) \wedge B(x)) \vdash \forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x)$

My proof needs to look like, I think:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{¬\exists x(A(x) \wedge B(x))}{
  \ldots\\
  A(a) \to \neg B(x)\\
  \forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x)
}
$

I cannot use $\mathbf{\exists E}$ since $\exists$ is not the main logical operator. How should I approach this proof ?

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\lnot \exists x(A(x) \land B(x)) \equiv \forall x \lnot(A(x) \land B(x))$?

Comment: Then you can use universal instantiation to show that, given the instantiation, you get $\lnot (A(a)\land B(a))$, and so $(\lnot A(a) \lor \lnot B(a))$, or $(A(a) \to \lnot B(a))$, and then you can use universal generalization.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use that. It wasn’t introduced, yet.

Comment: It should come in Chapter 34: Conversion of Quantifiers.

Comment: *Hint*: prove it by contradicition, assuming $\lnot \forall x (Ax \to \lnot Bx)$. Then assume  both $Ax$ and $Bx$.

Comment: Thank you, @MauroALLEGRANZA. Is this correct?
$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\neg\exists x(A(x) \wedge B(x))}{
 \fitch{\neg\forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x))}{
   \fitch{A(a)}{
     \fitch{B(a)}{
       A(a) \wedge B(a)\\
       \exists x(A(x) \wedge B(x))\\
       \bot
      }\\
      \neg B(a)
    }\\
    A(a) \to \neg B(a)\\
    \forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x))\\
    \bot
  }\\
  \forall x(A(x) \to \neg B(x))
}$$

Comment: Correct........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are off to a good start.   Now you need to introduce a conditional, so set it up: assume $A(a)$ hoping to derive $\neg B(a)$.   (NB: I prefer to note the assumption of an arbitrary variable.)

Thus you will need to introduce a negation, so set it up: assume $B(a)$ hoping to derive a contradiction.

Okay, so what can *you* contradict with the assumptions of $\neg\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))$, $A(a)$, and $B(b)$?

Then to prove equivalence you will need another subproof, which will involve introducing a negation, and inside that subproof *is where* you can use existential elimination.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{¬\exists x~(A(x) \wedge B(x))}{\fitch{[a]}{\fitch{A(a)}{\fitch{B(a)}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\neg B(a)}\\A(a)\to\neg B(a)}\\\forall x~(A(x)\to\neg B(x)}\\\neg\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))\to\forall x~(A(x)\to B(x))\\\fitch{\forall x~(A(x)\to\neg B(x))}{\fitch{\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))}{\fitch{[b]~A(b)\wedge B(b)}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\bot}\\\neg\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))}\\\forall x~(A(x)\to\neg B(x))\to\neg\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))\\\forall x~(A(x)\to\neg B(x))\gets\hspace{-2ex}\to\neg\exists x~(A(x)\wedge B(x))}$

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that both $\forall x (A(x)\to\neg B(x)$ and $A(a)\to\neg B(a)$ are  at the same level inside the subproof when you prove first implication ?

Comment: What's the meaning behind $[a]$ and $[b]$ ?

Comment: It is just to note the assumption of a variable.  $$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}{\fitch{[a]}{~\vdots\\ P(a)}\\\forall x~P(x)\qquad\forall\mathsf I}\qquad\raise{4ex}{\exists x~Q(x)\\\fitch{[b]~Q(b)}{~\vdots\\ R}\\R\qquad\exists\mathsf E}$$

Comment: Thank you. Would the proof you proposed look like this ?
[Fitch Proof](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1618p46he9mvqte/untitled%20note.png?dl=0)

Comment: Yes; well, the formatting seems a bit off, but that is the right approach.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. The formatting is corrected, now.
[Fitch Proff Revised](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1618p46he9mvqte/Untitled%20Note.png?dl=0)